# Ruby and rails perfomance issue, server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, passenger

I'm running a deployed rails webserver, and i'm experiencing memory issues. I get an Errno::ENOMEM error each time i try to invoke sendmail. When i run 'top' on my server, it shows me that 2 ruby1.8 processes are running, each digesting around 40% of memory. Is this caused by a leak in my code, or have I launched two simultaneous ruby processes?

Both processes are run by my deployer account, and following that they are invoked when I push to my production git repository (using pushand). I'm trying to find out if this is natural (ie. server needs to be upgraded) or if I have some kind of fault in my setup. I upgraded my RAM from 256 mb to 512 mb recently, and didn't have this problem before.

The problem is preventing visitors from creating a user, because the application throws an error when they should get an activation email.

Note that I'm running rails 2.1.0 on an ubuntu setup, with apache and passenger.

Comment: When I restart apache memory usage falls dramatically. I've decresed the PoolIdleTime setting from 1 day to 300 seconds, so every now and again the passenger processes will get killed.

Comment: I'm also looking into Rack::Bug, Oink and Memorylogic. I found [link](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/thats-not-a-memory-leak-its-bloat/) very useful.

Comment: The problem still persists though. I will try and optimization areas, and get back here if I find an answer.

Comment: It doesn't take long for the memory usage to go up to 80% (now 3 processes).

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys, I guess this was one of the cases where I had to help myself, and I'm actually pretty glad I did. I Didn't use any of the tools I linked to.

I logged in my server via. ssh and ran two commands in two screen windows: top and tail -f /var/www/mysite.com/log/production.log.

I looked in the live log file and noticed a page request that took a long time to load – a page where a user can get his/her images shown, where each user is identified by their name, via. acts_as_taggable_on. It took 6 seconds for this single request.

And it kept popping up. I think I saw it 6 or 7 times, and I decided to investigate it further. It was always the same user id, so I decided to look up the user. It turns out, the user had a blank name, "", and the tagged images is found by

```
Asset.tagged_with(@user.name, :on => "users")
```

Now in my app, there are 10s of thousands of assets, and Asset.tagged_with("", :on => "users") would return ALL of them, thus eating up my memory.

Now I've handled the case where a user has a blank name, and has it required for all new users. Even though no one helped, I still feel some gratitude towards stackoverflow, because sometimes its as simple as asking the questions to solve the problem.

Comment: Nice find, I don't think anyone would have been able to help you figure this out any better than your "talking to the wall" technique did. If your database supports CHECK constraints then I'd add one for this and make as many columns as possible NOT NULL for extra paranoia: broken code is easy to fix, broken data not so much.